# Gnome Activities Overview has no search bar

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

After upgrading to Fedora 31 my Activities Overview (when I press `super`) has no search bar. Typing something like 'terminal' and hitting enter also has no result, so it's not just a display issue. Everything else seems to be working find after the update. Is this configurable? A known bug? Something else?

My `gnome-shell` version is 3.34.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I experienced the same issue myself. After digging around for awhile I figured out that they removed "Activities Overview" from Gnome Classic, which is what Fedora 31 seems to use by default. To run "regular" Gnome:

1. Log out of your account
2. Click your username
3. Click the cog next to "Sign In"
4. Select "GNOME" instead of "GNOME Classic"

This restores the searching functionality, although it doesn't appear to feature the "Start Menu" anymore.